# Windows docker: Invalid reference format

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Following is my docker file content:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

MAINTAINER Amazon AI <sandeep.ganage@yahoo.in>


RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         wget \
         python3-pip \
         python3-setuptools \
         nginx \
         ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install numpy==1.16.2 scipy==1.2.1 scikit-learn==0.20.2 pandas flask gunicorn

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"

COPY decision_trees /opt/program
WORKDIR /opt/program
```

I built the docker image in windows power-shell with command `docker build -t tree-model .`

Now when I am trying to run the command:

```
docker run —rm -v $(pwd)/local_test/test_dir:/opt/ml tree-model train
```

It gives me the following error:

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I tried following options:

1. Instead of `$(pwd)/local_test/test_dir` I tried putting complete path: `D:/Sample/local_test/test_dir:/opt/ml`. It didn't work
2. Instead of `$(pwd)` I tried `${pwd}` it didn't work. (By the way $(pwd) prints the correct current directory, I tested it)
3. All combination with back and forward slash. Still no success.
4. All possible combinations with single and double quote on path. No success.

I am new to docker and never mounted a volume before. I tried other answers on stackoverflow but no success. Need help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running with git bash by any chance? If so, try giving in pure Windows format but double the backslashes. For example, I use something like C:\\dkrshare:/dkrshare. Seems git bash environment rewrites the paths given but docker does not like the rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

`$(pwd)` is a Linux thing. On Windows, you can use `%cd%`, so you'd write

```
docker run --rm -v %cd%/local_test/test_dir:/opt/ml tree-model train
```